# Seeking Help Understanding Difference between For Loop & .forEach

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

I have two functions that should produce the same result. I would like clarification as to why they do not. I'm not grasping the significant difference that must exist between for-loop and .forEach.

I'd like to though :)

```
//
//DEMO OBJECT WITH TWO ARRAYS
//
var myArray = {
    myList1 : [1,2,3,4],
    myList2 : [5,6,7,8]
}

//
//FUNCTION ONE: Produces the sum of myArray.myList1 as expected.
//
    var firstWay = function(){
        var sum = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i < myArray.myList2.length; i++){
            sum += myArray.myList2[i];
        }
        return sum
    };

var results2 = firstWay();
console.log(results2);



//FUNCTION TWO PRODUCES NaN
//1.) I don't know why it produced NaN.
//2.) I don't understand why this function wouldn't produce the same result as firstWay.

    var secondWay = function() {
       var sum = 0;
       myArray.myList1.forEach(function(cur){
          sum += cur.value; 
       });
       return sum;
    };

var results1 = secondWay();
console.log(results1);
```

Comment: numbers do not have a `.value` property, they _are_ the value.

Comment: Where is `calculateTotal()` defined?

Comment: To avoid confusion, don't name a variable `myArray` it is an array. In this case, `myArray` is an object with two array-valued properties.

Answer (score 0):

Remove value from `sum += cur.value` so it's just `sum += cur`. The `value` 
you need is already contained in `cur`.

```
var secondWay = function() {
   var sum = 0;
   myArray.myList1.forEach(function(cur){
      sum += cur; 
   });
   return sum;
};

var results1 = secondWay();
console.log(results1);
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped greatly. While my mistake seemed small, small mistakes are all it takes to mess things up.

Answer (score 0):

Many answers just stand in the doc and might be found by googling.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

> callback
>       Function to execute on each element. It accepts between one and three arguments:
>
> `currentValue`
>          The current element being processed in the array
>      `index` Optional
>          The index currentValue in the array
>      `array` Optional. 
>         The array forEach() was called upon    "

So `cur` in your code is the current element of your array of integers. So it's an integer. So it has no value property, it IS the value you're looking for, as pointed out in a comment.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question. The last two lines of your answer were found to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On the second iteration you wrongly put `sum += cur.value`. 
The right way shoud be : `sum += cur`.